# taskjuggler w/ multiple dependencies where task length depends on previous tasks

Tags: project-management, wolfram-mathematica, traveling-salesman

I have a task Z that can only be completed once *either* task X or 
task Y is completed. Also:

% The length of task Z depends on which of X or Y is completed:

% If task X is completed, task Z takes 4 hours

% If task Y is completed, task Z takes 7 hours

% Task X takes 5 hours to complete

% Task Y takes 3 hours to complete

% Task X and task Y are exclusive: you can't do both (but that's 
 probably irrelevant, since that would never be optimal)

The question: what's the quickest I can complete task Z?

In this case, the answer is obviously 9 hours (X then Z), but my real 
problem has many cases like this.

Can taskjuggler help me? Can another tool? Additional notes:

% This is an extension of the "traveling salesman problem", and thus 
 NP-hard. I'd be happy with a good-but-non-optimal solution.

% In the actual problem, some tasks are "milestones" which have a 
 non-negative value. My goal is to maximize the sum of these 
 values. However, I'm more than happy to solve the minimum time 
 problem first. Additionally, the values may be equal for all 
 milestones, simplifying the problem.

NB: since Mathematica has a function to quickly (but non-optimally) solve the TravelingSalesman problem, adding it as a tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into dynamic programming.  Basically, you'll reuse the solutions to subproblems to build a solution for your whole problem.  You can do this in Mathematica or most any programming language.